# redirect IP on osx

Tags: mac-osx, ifconfig, ip-forwarding, ipfw

On my Mac OS X (10.6.8) I'd like to make all requests for `111.111.111.111` go to `222.222.222.222` for all ports. To test this, I have a webserver at `222.222.222.222:80` which will respond with a page for any host. e.g:

- http://222.222.222.222/
- http://whatever.222.222.222.222.xip.io/
- http://host.which.resolves.to.that.server/

I've tried doing the following:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 222.222.222.222 alias
sudo ipfw add fwd 111.111.111.111 tcp from me to 222.222.222.222
```

But trying to access `http://111.111.111.111/` doesn't give me anything. I think this is related to the fact that although the redirect is there, the tcp packet's destination IP is not rewritten.

Where should I look next to solve this? Should I also look into using natd?

Answer (score 0):

OSX 10.6.8 uses Apache web server. The config files are usually found in /etc/apache2/

You may want to try [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Covering *all* ports is another matter. I think it requires some network/port address translation, about which I know little